¿Cómo agregar una clase a diferentes elementos con mosueenter?
Tengo varios elementos a los cuales quiero que de forma individual cada vez que pase el mouse por uno de ellos se le agregue una clase que  haga visible un contenedor con botones.

No sé que estoy haciendo mal, ya que cuando paso el mouse no añade la clase al elemento especifico sobre el cual pase, sino que la añade al primer elemento del contenedor.
En la imagen por ejemplo si yo paso por el elemento que tiene la flecha azul, la clase se la agrega al primer elemento y no al que yo estoy seleccionando.
Creación de la tarjeta de elementos
const uniContainer=document.querySelector(".products_container");
const createList=(products)=>{
    products.forEach(unidad => {
        const newUniDen=document.createElement("div");
        newUniDen.className="product_element"
        newUniDen.innerHTML=`
        <img src= ${unidad.image} />
        <div class="actionButtons_container">
            <div class="action_buttons">
                <svg class="addToCart_button" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M90 190h67.3v67.3c0 11.3 9.1 20.4 20.4 20.4s20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4V190h67.3c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4s-9.1-20.4-20.4-20.4h-67.3V81.8c0-11.3-9.1-20.4-20.4-20.4s-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4v67.3H90c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4S78.8 190 90 190"/><path d="M475.4 10.8h-98.5c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4V312H36.9c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4s9.1 20.4 20.4 20.4h339.9c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4V51.7h78.1c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4.1-11.3-9.1-20.5-20.3-20.5M129.1 363.4C91 363.4 60 394.2 60 432.1s31 68.7 69.1 68.7 69.1-30.8 69.1-68.7-31-68.7-69.1-68.7m0 96.6c-15.6 0-28.3-12.5-28.3-27.9s12.7-27.9 28.3-27.9 28.3 12.5 28.3 27.9-12.7 27.9-28.3 27.9m177-96.6c-38.1 0-69.1 30.8-69.1 68.7s31 68.7 69.1 68.7 69.1-30.8 69.1-68.7-31-68.7-69.1-68.7m0 96.6c-15.6 0-28.3-12.5-28.3-27.9s12.7-27.9 28.3-27.9 28.3 12.5 28.3 27.9-12.7 27.9-28.3 27.9"/></svg>
                <svg  class="search_button" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M21.71 20.29 18 16.61A9 9 0 1 0 16.61 18l3.68 3.68a1 1 0 0 0 1.42 0 1 1 0 0 0 0-1.39M11 18a7 7 0 1 1 7-7 7 7 0 0 1-7 7"/></svg>
                <svg class="favorite_button" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-name="Line Color" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon line-color"><path d="M19.57 5.44a4.91 4.91 0 0 1 0 6.93L12 20l-7.57-7.63A4.91 4.91 0 0 1 7.87 4a4.9 4.9 0 0 1 3.44 1.44 4.5 4.5 0 0 1 .69.88 4.5 4.5 0 0 1 .69-.88 4.83 4.83 0 0 1 6.88 0" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:2"/></svg>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span>${unidad.name}</span>
        <span>${unidad.price}</span>
        `
        uniContainer.append(newUniDen);
    });
}
createList(uniDent);

Añadir clase
const content=document.querySelectorAll(".product_element")
const buttonShow=document.querySelector(".actionButtons_container")
console.log(content)

content.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener("mouseenter",()=>{
        buttonShow.classList.add("showbtn");
    });
    item.addEventListener("mouseleave",()=>{
        buttonShow.classList.remove("showbtn");
    })
});


El problema está en el código JavaScript:
const content=document.querySelectorAll(".product_element")
const buttonShow=document.querySelector(".actionButtons_container")
console.log(content)

content.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener("mouseenter",()=>{
        buttonShow.classList.add("showbtn");
    });
    item.addEventListener("mouseleave",()=>{
        buttonShow.classList.remove("showbtn");
    })
});

Estás seleccionando todas las tarjetas con querySelectorAll, pero a la hora de seleccionar los botones, estás usando querySelector que sólo seleccionará el primero que encuentre (en este caso, los botones de la primera tarjeta.
La solución es simple: mueve la definición de buttonShow dentro de la función que crea los listener de eventos y hazlo a partir del elemento en sí (item) en vez del documento. De ese modo, el buttonShow será único para cada uno de ellos.


const content = document.querySelectorAll(".product_element");


content.forEach(item => {
  // mueve buttonShow aqui y selecciona desde el producto actual y no document
  const buttonShow = item.querySelector(".actionButtons_container");
  
  item.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    buttonShow.classList.add("showbtn");
  });
  item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    buttonShow.classList.remove("showbtn");
  })
});
.product_element {
  display: inline-block;
}

svg {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

.action_buttons {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.showbtn .action_buttons {
  visibility: visible;
}
<div class="product_element">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x100" />
  <div class="actionButtons_container">
    <div class="action_buttons">
      <svg class="addToCart_button" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M90 190h67.3v67.3c0 11.3 9.1 20.4 20.4 20.4s20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4V190h67.3c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4s-9.1-20.4-20.4-20.4h-67.3V81.8c0-11.3-9.1-20.4-20.4-20.4s-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4v67.3H90c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4S78.8 190 90 190"/><path d="M475.4 10.8h-98.5c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4V312H36.9c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4s9.1 20.4 20.4 20.4h339.9c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4V51.7h78.1c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4.1-11.3-9.1-20.5-20.3-20.5M129.1 363.4C91 363.4 60 394.2 60 432.1s31 68.7 69.1 68.7 69.1-30.8 69.1-68.7-31-68.7-69.1-68.7m0 96.6c-15.6 0-28.3-12.5-28.3-27.9s12.7-27.9 28.3-27.9 28.3 12.5 28.3 27.9-12.7 27.9-28.3 27.9m177-96.6c-38.1 0-69.1 30.8-69.1 68.7s31 68.7 69.1 68.7 69.1-30.8 69.1-68.7-31-68.7-69.1-68.7m0 96.6c-15.6 0-28.3-12.5-28.3-27.9s12.7-27.9 28.3-27.9 28.3 12.5 28.3 27.9-12.7 27.9-28.3 27.9"/></svg>
      <svg class="search_button" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M21.71 20.29 18 16.61A9 9 0 1 0 16.61 18l3.68 3.68a1 1 0 0 0 1.42 0 1 1 0 0 0 0-1.39M11 18a7 7 0 1 1 7-7 7 7 0 0 1-7 7"/></svg>
      <svg class="favorite_button" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-name="Line Color" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon line-color"><path d="M19.57 5.44a4.91 4.91 0 0 1 0 6.93L12 20l-7.57-7.63A4.91 4.91 0 0 1 7.87 4a4.9 4.9 0 0 1 3.44 1.44 4.5 4.5 0 0 1 .69.88 4.5 4.5 0 0 1 .69-.88 4.83 4.83 0 0 1 6.88 0" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:2"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>NAME A</span>
  <span>PRICE A</span>
</div>
<div class="product_element">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x100" />
  <div class="actionButtons_container">
    <div class="action_buttons">
      <svg class="addToCart_button" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M90 190h67.3v67.3c0 11.3 9.1 20.4 20.4 20.4s20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4V190h67.3c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4s-9.1-20.4-20.4-20.4h-67.3V81.8c0-11.3-9.1-20.4-20.4-20.4s-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4v67.3H90c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4S78.8 190 90 190"/><path d="M475.4 10.8h-98.5c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4V312H36.9c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4s9.1 20.4 20.4 20.4h339.9c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4V51.7h78.1c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4.1-11.3-9.1-20.5-20.3-20.5M129.1 363.4C91 363.4 60 394.2 60 432.1s31 68.7 69.1 68.7 69.1-30.8 69.1-68.7-31-68.7-69.1-68.7m0 96.6c-15.6 0-28.3-12.5-28.3-27.9s12.7-27.9 28.3-27.9 28.3 12.5 28.3 27.9-12.7 27.9-28.3 27.9m177-96.6c-38.1 0-69.1 30.8-69.1 68.7s31 68.7 69.1 68.7 69.1-30.8 69.1-68.7-31-68.7-69.1-68.7m0 96.6c-15.6 0-28.3-12.5-28.3-27.9s12.7-27.9 28.3-27.9 28.3 12.5 28.3 27.9-12.7 27.9-28.3 27.9"/></svg>
      <svg class="search_button" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M21.71 20.29 18 16.61A9 9 0 1 0 16.61 18l3.68 3.68a1 1 0 0 0 1.42 0 1 1 0 0 0 0-1.39M11 18a7 7 0 1 1 7-7 7 7 0 0 1-7 7"/></svg>
      <svg class="favorite_button" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-name="Line Color" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon line-color"><path d="M19.57 5.44a4.91 4.91 0 0 1 0 6.93L12 20l-7.57-7.63A4.91 4.91 0 0 1 7.87 4a4.9 4.9 0 0 1 3.44 1.44 4.5 4.5 0 0 1 .69.88 4.5 4.5 0 0 1 .69-.88 4.83 4.83 0 0 1 6.88 0" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:2"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>NAME B</span>
  <span>PRICE B</span>
</div>
<div class="product_element">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x100" />
  <div class="actionButtons_container">
    <div class="action_buttons">
      <svg class="addToCart_button" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M90 190h67.3v67.3c0 11.3 9.1 20.4 20.4 20.4s20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4V190h67.3c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4s-9.1-20.4-20.4-20.4h-67.3V81.8c0-11.3-9.1-20.4-20.4-20.4s-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4v67.3H90c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4S78.8 190 90 190"/><path d="M475.4 10.8h-98.5c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4V312H36.9c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4s9.1 20.4 20.4 20.4h339.9c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4V51.7h78.1c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4.1-11.3-9.1-20.5-20.3-20.5M129.1 363.4C91 363.4 60 394.2 60 432.1s31 68.7 69.1 68.7 69.1-30.8 69.1-68.7-31-68.7-69.1-68.7m0 96.6c-15.6 0-28.3-12.5-28.3-27.9s12.7-27.9 28.3-27.9 28.3 12.5 28.3 27.9-12.7 27.9-28.3 27.9m177-96.6c-38.1 0-69.1 30.8-69.1 68.7s31 68.7 69.1 68.7 69.1-30.8 69.1-68.7-31-68.7-69.1-68.7m0 96.6c-15.6 0-28.3-12.5-28.3-27.9s12.7-27.9 28.3-27.9 28.3 12.5 28.3 27.9-12.7 27.9-28.3 27.9"/></svg>
      <svg class="search_button" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M21.71 20.29 18 16.61A9 9 0 1 0 16.61 18l3.68 3.68a1 1 0 0 0 1.42 0 1 1 0 0 0 0-1.39M11 18a7 7 0 1 1 7-7 7 7 0 0 1-7 7"/></svg>
      <svg class="favorite_button" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-name="Line Color" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon line-color"><path d="M19.57 5.44a4.91 4.91 0 0 1 0 6.93L12 20l-7.57-7.63A4.91 4.91 0 0 1 7.87 4a4.9 4.9 0 0 1 3.44 1.44 4.5 4.5 0 0 1 .69.88 4.5 4.5 0 0 1 .69-.88 4.83 4.83 0 0 1 6.88 0" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:2"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>NAME C</span>
  <span>PRICE C</span>
</div>




Te voy a poner otra respuesta, con una alternativa algo diferente: puedes ahorrarte todo el código JS para gestionar si el ratón está o no está por encima del producto y delegar eso al navegador usando CSS. Esto puede ser una alternativa interesante si lo único para lo que añades la clase es para mostrar/ocultar los botones.
Los pasos a seguir:

Quita el código JavaScript que gestiona el ratón entrando y saliendo

Quita los estilos asociados con la clase .showbtn (de nuevo, sólo si es su único propósito)

Añade estás 3 líneas a tu CSS:
 .product_element:hover .action_buttons {
   visibility: visible;
   /* o display: block o el método que uses para mostrarlo */
 }



¡Y ya está! Con CSS, le estás diciendo al navegador que cada vez que el ratón esté encima del elemento .product_element muestre el contenedor de los botones (que por cierto deberían ser botones en vez de imágenes, pero esa es otra historia).
Si quieres que sea más robusto, puedes añadir una línea más para que no sólo estén visibles cuando se pase el ratón por encima, si no también cuando tenga el foco el elemento o alguno de sus descendientes.
Aquí dejo una demo de cómo se vería:


.product_element {
  display: inline-block;
}

svg {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

.action_buttons {
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* este es el código que quieres */
.product_element:hover .action_buttons,
.product_element:focus-within .action_buttons {
  visibility: visible;
}
<div class="product_element">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x100" />
  <div class="actionButtons_container">
    <div class="action_buttons">
      <svg class="addToCart_button" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M90 190h67.3v67.3c0 11.3 9.1 20.4 20.4 20.4s20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4V190h67.3c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4s-9.1-20.4-20.4-20.4h-67.3V81.8c0-11.3-9.1-20.4-20.4-20.4s-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4v67.3H90c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4S78.8 190 90 190"/><path d="M475.4 10.8h-98.5c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4V312H36.9c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4s9.1 20.4 20.4 20.4h339.9c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4V51.7h78.1c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4.1-11.3-9.1-20.5-20.3-20.5M129.1 363.4C91 363.4 60 394.2 60 432.1s31 68.7 69.1 68.7 69.1-30.8 69.1-68.7-31-68.7-69.1-68.7m0 96.6c-15.6 0-28.3-12.5-28.3-27.9s12.7-27.9 28.3-27.9 28.3 12.5 28.3 27.9-12.7 27.9-28.3 27.9m177-96.6c-38.1 0-69.1 30.8-69.1 68.7s31 68.7 69.1 68.7 69.1-30.8 69.1-68.7-31-68.7-69.1-68.7m0 96.6c-15.6 0-28.3-12.5-28.3-27.9s12.7-27.9 28.3-27.9 28.3 12.5 28.3 27.9-12.7 27.9-28.3 27.9"/></svg>
      <svg class="search_button" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M21.71 20.29 18 16.61A9 9 0 1 0 16.61 18l3.68 3.68a1 1 0 0 0 1.42 0 1 1 0 0 0 0-1.39M11 18a7 7 0 1 1 7-7 7 7 0 0 1-7 7"/></svg>
      <svg class="favorite_button" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-name="Line Color" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon line-color"><path d="M19.57 5.44a4.91 4.91 0 0 1 0 6.93L12 20l-7.57-7.63A4.91 4.91 0 0 1 7.87 4a4.9 4.9 0 0 1 3.44 1.44 4.5 4.5 0 0 1 .69.88 4.5 4.5 0 0 1 .69-.88 4.83 4.83 0 0 1 6.88 0" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:2"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>NAME A</span>
  <span>PRICE A</span>
</div>
<div class="product_element">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x100" />
  <div class="actionButtons_container">
    <div class="action_buttons">
      <svg class="addToCart_button" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M90 190h67.3v67.3c0 11.3 9.1 20.4 20.4 20.4s20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4V190h67.3c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4s-9.1-20.4-20.4-20.4h-67.3V81.8c0-11.3-9.1-20.4-20.4-20.4s-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4v67.3H90c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4S78.8 190 90 190"/><path d="M475.4 10.8h-98.5c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4V312H36.9c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4s9.1 20.4 20.4 20.4h339.9c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4V51.7h78.1c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4.1-11.3-9.1-20.5-20.3-20.5M129.1 363.4C91 363.4 60 394.2 60 432.1s31 68.7 69.1 68.7 69.1-30.8 69.1-68.7-31-68.7-69.1-68.7m0 96.6c-15.6 0-28.3-12.5-28.3-27.9s12.7-27.9 28.3-27.9 28.3 12.5 28.3 27.9-12.7 27.9-28.3 27.9m177-96.6c-38.1 0-69.1 30.8-69.1 68.7s31 68.7 69.1 68.7 69.1-30.8 69.1-68.7-31-68.7-69.1-68.7m0 96.6c-15.6 0-28.3-12.5-28.3-27.9s12.7-27.9 28.3-27.9 28.3 12.5 28.3 27.9-12.7 27.9-28.3 27.9"/></svg>
      <svg class="search_button" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M21.71 20.29 18 16.61A9 9 0 1 0 16.61 18l3.68 3.68a1 1 0 0 0 1.42 0 1 1 0 0 0 0-1.39M11 18a7 7 0 1 1 7-7 7 7 0 0 1-7 7"/></svg>
      <svg class="favorite_button" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-name="Line Color" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon line-color"><path d="M19.57 5.44a4.91 4.91 0 0 1 0 6.93L12 20l-7.57-7.63A4.91 4.91 0 0 1 7.87 4a4.9 4.9 0 0 1 3.44 1.44 4.5 4.5 0 0 1 .69.88 4.5 4.5 0 0 1 .69-.88 4.83 4.83 0 0 1 6.88 0" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:2"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>NAME B</span>
  <span>PRICE B</span>
</div>
<div class="product_element">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x100" />
  <div class="actionButtons_container">
    <div class="action_buttons">
      <svg class="addToCart_button" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M90 190h67.3v67.3c0 11.3 9.1 20.4 20.4 20.4s20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4V190h67.3c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4s-9.1-20.4-20.4-20.4h-67.3V81.8c0-11.3-9.1-20.4-20.4-20.4s-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4v67.3H90c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4S78.8 190 90 190"/><path d="M475.4 10.8h-98.5c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4V312H36.9c-11.3 0-20.4 9.1-20.4 20.4s9.1 20.4 20.4 20.4h339.9c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4V51.7h78.1c11.3 0 20.4-9.1 20.4-20.4.1-11.3-9.1-20.5-20.3-20.5M129.1 363.4C91 363.4 60 394.2 60 432.1s31 68.7 69.1 68.7 69.1-30.8 69.1-68.7-31-68.7-69.1-68.7m0 96.6c-15.6 0-28.3-12.5-28.3-27.9s12.7-27.9 28.3-27.9 28.3 12.5 28.3 27.9-12.7 27.9-28.3 27.9m177-96.6c-38.1 0-69.1 30.8-69.1 68.7s31 68.7 69.1 68.7 69.1-30.8 69.1-68.7-31-68.7-69.1-68.7m0 96.6c-15.6 0-28.3-12.5-28.3-27.9s12.7-27.9 28.3-27.9 28.3 12.5 28.3 27.9-12.7 27.9-28.3 27.9"/></svg>
      <svg class="search_button" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M21.71 20.29 18 16.61A9 9 0 1 0 16.61 18l3.68 3.68a1 1 0 0 0 1.42 0 1 1 0 0 0 0-1.39M11 18a7 7 0 1 1 7-7 7 7 0 0 1-7 7"/></svg>
      <svg class="favorite_button" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-name="Line Color" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon line-color"><path d="M19.57 5.44a4.91 4.91 0 0 1 0 6.93L12 20l-7.57-7.63A4.91 4.91 0 0 1 7.87 4a4.9 4.9 0 0 1 3.44 1.44 4.5 4.5 0 0 1 .69.88 4.5 4.5 0 0 1 .69-.88 4.83 4.83 0 0 1 6.88 0" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:2"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>NAME C</span>
  <span>PRICE C</span>
</div>



Hace básicamente lo mismo que la otra solución que te puse, pero con menos código y mantenido/gestionado por el navegador.
